# Alignment of fractions of the form (a-b)/(c-d)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, fractions

The fraction \frac{num}{den} are usually rendered by centering the numerator and the denominator.

Unfortunately, I find the result in the following MWE quite ugly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

If $r\neq 1$, then 

\[
\sum_{k=0}^nr^k = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}
\]

\end{document}
```

Indeed, the $r^{n+1}$ part is too big. I wish that the two - signs of a fraction of the form \frac{a-b}{c-d} to be vertically aligned (whatever the size of a,b,c and d) at the center of the fraction, in order to show the symmetry of the formula.

**How can I get such a result?**

Note: if it matters for the answer, I would like the alignment to work also for inline maths mode.

Comment: Unrelated point 1, `\displaystyle` isn't a command, it's a switch, like `{\bfseries foo}` In its role as a switch it will almost never need braces, but if it did need them, they would have to be like `{\displaystyle }`. That's the general rule for switches anyway, although I'm not sure `\displaystyle` would be very happy with you if you tried to scope it like this, I haven't tried. Unrelated point 2, `\[ ... \]` enters display math mode by definition, so `\displaystyle` is completely redundant

Comment: What do you mean by working in non-maths mode? You can't use `\frac{}{}` in text mode so no solution can possibly be applicable there.

Comment: @au101: thanks a lot. I had been taught the wrong way. I edited the code.

Comment: @cfr: I meant inline.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

[image: possibility]

That looks pretty ugly to me, but they say beauty is in the eye of the beholder ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

  If $r\neq 1$, then
  \[
  \sum_{k=0}^nr^k = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r^{\phantom{n+1}}}
  \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's what I am looking for. Maybe with some space on the left, so that the minus signs have a central position. Is there a way I can make it automatic? A a macro \diffratio{a}{b}{c}{d}?

Comment: I find ”ugly“ too weak for describing that output.

Comment: The problem with this layout is that it looks like the printer has accidentally left out an index from the denominator.

Answer (score 3):

If you really think this is what you want, here's the `\diffratio` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\diffratio}[4]{%
  \frac
    {\diffratio@left{#1}{#3}-\diffratio@right{#2}{#4}}
    {\diffratio@left{#3}{#1}-\diffratio@right{#4}{#2}}%
}

\newcommand{\diffratio@left}[2]{%
  \mathpalette\diffratio@left@i{{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\diffratio@right}[2]{%
  \mathpalette\diffratio@right@i{{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand\diffratio@left@i[2]{%
  \diffratio@measure{#1}{#2}%
  \hb@xt@\dimen@{\hss\box\z@}%
}
\newcommand\diffratio@right@i[2]{%
  \diffratio@measure{#1}{#2}%
  \hb@xt@\dimen@{\box\z@\hss}%
}
\newcommand\diffratio@measure[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\@firstoftwo#2$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$\m@th#1\@secondoftwo#2$}%
  \dimen@=\wd\z@
  \ifdim\wd\tw@>\dimen@ \dimen@=\wd\tw@\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\diffratio{1}{x^{n+1}}{1}{x} \qquad \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} \\
\diffratio{a}{bc}{xy}{z} \qquad \frac{a-bc}{xy-z}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have no doubt whatsoever that the normal `\frac` way is better.

Comment: Aesthetically the normal way is of course better.  I'm even struggling to think of a teaching situation where this would be useful.  And what happens (more a question for the OP, but also what happens with this the code) if you have `\frac{a-b}{a-b-c}`?

Comment: @ChrisH There's no natural alignment possible in your example.

Comment: I thought you'd say that.  And I see you've put the onus on the user to make the decision as to where to break it

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the two to line up, you need to add `\phantom` as a space filler.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% for \mathrlap

\begin{document}

If $r\neq 1$, then 

\[
\sum_{k=0}^nr^k = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r^{\phantom{n+1}}}
 = \frac{1-r^{\mathrlap{n+1}}}{1-r} \phantom{\scriptstyle n+1}\textrm{with added white space}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]