# How to align 2 equations in fraction at `=`?

Tags: typography, alignment, fractions

I was trying to answer this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275317/aligning-equal-signs-in-the-numerator-and-denominator-of-a-fraction) on another stackexchange forum, to say that they could use Latex instead, only to find I can't figure how to do this in Latex myself.

Is it possible to have 2 equations one in the numerator and one in denominator, be aligned at `=` in each? Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\frac{\text{test} = 0.01}{\text{testing} = 0.01}$
\end{document}
```

Gives

[image]

I'd like these two to be aligned at `=`.  Just like when one uses `align*` environment, except inside a fraction now.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\text{test} &= 0.01 \\
\text{testing} &= 0.01
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

TL 2022

**Update**
Thanks for all the answers. Wish I can accept them all. I picked

```
\[
\begin{aligned}
\text{test}&=0.01 \\
\hline
\text{testing}&=0.01
\end{aligned}
\]
```

Because it was easiest for me to understand how it works. But all answers are really great.

Comment: Crosslink to some related question on fraction-align: 
[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/333439) 
[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/619051)
[3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/639182) 
[4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/424708) 
[5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84243) 
[6](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/584265) 
(although not at `=`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is, of course, not a fraction. But it's easy to emulate one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned}
\text{test}&=0.01 \\
\hline
\text{testing}&=0.01
\end{aligned}
=
\frac{0.01}{0.01}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The spacing is not exactly the same, though.

Just for fun.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0.14ex}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0.22ex}
\begin{aligned}
\addlinespace[0.04ex]
\text{test}&=0.01 \\
\midrule[0.4pt]
\text{testing}&=0.01
\end{aligned}
=
\frac{0.01}{0.01}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Use some `\phantom`s and over`lap`ping:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\frac{\text{test} = 0.01}{\text{testing} = 0.01}$

$\frac{\phantom{\text{testing}}\mathllap{\text{test}} = 0.01}{\text{testing} = 0.01}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Pretty trick. Good job and easy to use! You should propose a dedicated macro.

Comment: Here is one proposition of name `\newcommand\samelenas[2]{\phantom{\text{#2}}\mathllap{\text{#1}}}`.

Answer (score 9):

One possibility is to use an array.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{r@{}c@{}l}
\text{test}&{}={}&0.01 \\\hline
\text{testing}&{}={}&0.01
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Not to argue this as a preferred approach, but nonetheless, `tabstackengine` can achieve the desired result.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[TABcline]{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\setstackgap{S}{1pt}
\vcenter{\hbox{\alignShortstack{
\text{test} \mathstrut=& 0.01 \\
\TABcline{1-2}
\text{testing} \mathstrut=& 0.01}}} = 0
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]